# Django doc app is does not have CSS gives error HTML file does not exist

Tags: python, html, django, python-sphinx

I have a Django 1.5 project in which I have created an API app and has been documented with sphinx 1.2b2. I wanted to use the documentation to be accessed like a webpage when the site is placed in server.

I did a little research and found that there is an app named django-docs, I have installed qith this configurations:

settings.py:

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
DOCS_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, '../docs/_build/html/')
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/', include('app.api.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^docs/', include('docs.urls')),
)
```

Whenever I access "/docs/" I can see the index.html of my sphinx documentation, but it has no CSS styles
When I click the "API" link, the url looks like this: "/docs/_file/api.html" but page continues displaying index.html. And when I click "API" link again, the url looks like this "/docs/_file/_file/api.html" and the page shows an error:

> "/../docs/_build/html/_files/_files/api.html" does not exist

How can I solve the link references? How can I add the static CSS files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the sphinx version to 1.1.3 and it work correctly.